# How to compare with a rules condition vote:uid to 10 instances?

Tags: rules, rating, database

**Principle**: limit user's votes to 10.

**Modules used**: Voting API, Rate (or maybe Plus1)

**Context**: Users can vote on projects with 10 possible votes to distribut on all projects, by 1 to 10 votes on each project of their choices, up to a total of 10 votes.

When a user has distributed 10 votes, he loses the permission to vote. 
To swith the permission with rules, I create a role "Voter". All users have the role by default.

At that point, I have this:
- Event : content is viewed (of type project)
- Condition : site:current-user:uid equals vote:uid
//And now I'd like to say something like "AND vote:uid appears 10 times in the 'votingapi_votes'.'uid' SO
- Action : Add/remove user role to simple AU (without vote permission)

So how to compare with a rule condition vote:uid to 10 instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario you describe, a simple solution could be to create a profile field to store the number of votes per user. This field will be:

- set to 0 as a default value
- incremented when the user votes (you can use Rules for that, there is an action called "Set a data value")
- compared with your defined maximum (ex: 10) in Rules, so that when the user reaches 10, something is triggered (ex: Remove user role: "Voting User")

You can then set the voting API permissions to this role ("Voting User"), and use it as a display condition to hide the voting buttons (Plus 1 or Rate).

Hope it helps!
Cheers